# db2 insert by select value from different table

Tags: insert, db2

i'm trying to insert into 1 table where one of the field is the running where need to increment when insert, so i create insert sql as below

```
 INSERT INTO ICGR1100(C_IST, NUM_RIF, C_ORO, NUM_SER, TMSP_CAR, 
                      C_AG_CAR, C_MATR_CAR, C_TP_MAG, DT_RIC, C_FORN, 
                      IMP_PREM, DT_PAGM_PREM, IMP_ACQ, DT_ACQ, IMP_VEND, 
                      DT_VEND, F_GRTS, TMSP_ULT_AGG, C_MATR_ULT_AGG) 
 VALUES('01', (SELECT MAX_NUM_RIF 
                 FROM FINAL TABLE(UPDATE ICGR1005 
                 SET MAX_NUM_RIF = CAST(CAST((CAST(MAX_NUM_RIF AS DECIMAL(16))+1)
                                   AS DECIMAL(16)) AS CHAR(16)) WHERE C_IST='01')), 
                 '005', '0000000000357209', '2011-11-23 17:00:00.000', 
                 '90109', 'Gold', '03', '20111122', '001', 17900, '20111122', 
                 1667500, '20111122', 1795395, '20111122', '0', 
                 '2011-11-23 17:00:00.000', 'Gold')
```

but getting error as 
DB2 SQL Error:

```
SQLCODE=-20165, SQLSTATE=428FL, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

Message:

```
An SQL data change statement within a FROM  clause is not allowed in the context in which it was specified.. `SQLCODE=-20165, SQLSTATE=428FL, DRIVER=3.50.152`
```

can anyone advice me

thanks in advance

Comment: What version of DB2 - iSeries, LUW?  I don't believe that using a data-change reference (the `FROM FINAL TABLE` bit) is valid on the iSeries for anything other than a regular `SELECT` after an `INSERT` (no `UPDATE`, sorry).  (as of V6R1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok easy solution, i just run increment first then insert as below:

```
UPDATE ICGR1005 SET MAX_NUM_RIF=CAST(CAST((CAST(MAX_NUM_RIF AS DECIMAL(16))+1) AS DECIMAL(16)) AS CHAR(16)) WHERE C_IST='01';
INSERT INTO ICGR1100(C_IST, NUM_RIF, C_ORO, NUM_SER, TMSP_CAR, C_AG_CAR, C_MATR_CAR, C_TP_MAG, DT_RIC, C_FORN, IMP_PREM, DT_PAGM_PREM, IMP_ACQ, DT_ACQ, IMP_VEND, DT_VEND, F_GRTS, TMSP_ULT_AGG, C_MATR_ULT_AGG) 
VALUES('01', (SELECT MAX_NUM_RIF FROM ICGR1005), '005', '0000000000357209', '2011-11-23 17:00:00.000', '90109', 'Gold', '03', '20111122', '001', 17900, '20111122', 1729000, '20111122', 1869138, '20111122', '0', '2011-11-23 17:00:00.000', 'Gold');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
INSERT INTO ICGR1100 (
    C_IST, NUM_RIF, C_ORO, NUM_SER, TMSP_CAR, C_AG_CAR, C_MATR_CAR, C_TP_MAG, DT_RIC,     C_FORN, IMP_PREM, DT_PAGM_PREM, MP_ACQ, DT_ACQ, IMP_VEND, DT_VEND, F_GRTS, TMSP_ULT_AGG, C_MATR_ULT_AGG
)
SELECT
    '01', MAX_NUM_RIF, '005', '0000000000357209', '2011-11-23 17:00:00.000', '90109', 'Gold', '03', '20111122', '001', 17900, '20111122', 1667500, '20111122', 1795395, '20111122', '0', '2011-11-23 17:00:00.000', 'Gold'
FROM FINAL TABLE (
    UPDATE ICGR1005
    SET
        MAX_NUM_RIF = CAST(CAST((CAST(MAX_NUM_RIF AS DECIMAL(16))+1) AS DECIMAL(16)) AS CHAR(16))
    WHERE C_IST = '01'
)
```

If this does not work, I would suggest posting relevant CREATE and INSERT statements, so that we can run a test locally.